# C++ and Lua with SQLite

Tags: c++, sqlite, lua

I have C++ with Lua binding. All is OK, but if I add SQLite, my scripts stop working (not even an empty script with just one `print` runs).

In my C++ code, I call

```
luaL_openlibs( this->state );
luaopen_lsqlite3(this->state); /* sqlite */
```

If I do this, Lua script no longer works.

If I remove (comment out) `luaopen_lsqlite3`, scripts are working (but obviously without SQLite). What is wrong? Or what I need to call?

I am using http://lua.sqlite.org/index.cgi/index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution, that requires to edit Lua source files.

---

In **lualib.h** add

```
#define LUA_SQLLIBNAME  "lsqlite3"
LUAMOD_API int (luaopen_lsqlite3)(lua_State *L);
```

before

```
LUALIB_API void (luaL_openlibs) (lua_State *L);
```

---

In **linit.h** add this `{LUA_SQLLIBNAME, luaopen_lsqlite3 }` to `loadedlibs` array. You get

```
static const luaL_Reg loadedlibs[] = {
  {"_G", luaopen_base},
  {LUA_LOADLIBNAME, luaopen_package},
  {LUA_COLIBNAME, luaopen_coroutine},
  {LUA_TABLIBNAME, luaopen_table},
  {LUA_IOLIBNAME, luaopen_io},
  {LUA_OSLIBNAME, luaopen_os},
  {LUA_STRLIBNAME, luaopen_string},
  {LUA_BITLIBNAME, luaopen_bit32},
  {LUA_MATHLIBNAME, luaopen_math},
  {LUA_DBLIBNAME, luaopen_debug},
  {LUA_SQLLIBNAME, luaopen_lsqlite3 },
  {NULL, NULL}
};
```

---

Now, If you call luaL_openlibs, SQLite support will be in your code after calling `local sqlite3 = require("lsqlite3")` in Lua

Comment: Amazing, spot on.  Thanks.